# how to Perform Divide operations in Pyspark while updating the column?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have a SQL Query which I want to change into pyspark. we have a Column called CGPA which contains some values and i need to divide the values by 25 where our conditions are matching

```
UPDATE STUDENT_TABLE 
SET STUDENT_TABLE.CGPA = ([STUDENT_TABLE].CGPA/25)
WHERE (((STUDENT_TABLE.CGPA)>"5" Or (STUDENT_TABLE.CGPA)="100"));
```

The Pyspark Code i am trying is not working

```
df=df.withColumn('CGPA' , F.when((col('CGPA') > '5') & (col('CGPA') == '100'),(df.CGPA/25) .otherwise(df['CGPA])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken the following sample data for my dataframe to demonstrate.

```
data = [[1,4],[2,10],[3,40],[4,100],[5,0],[6,5]]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=['id','CGPA'])
display(df)
```

[image]

- Looking at your SQL query, as you want to update when either of the conditions is true (i.e., or condition in SQL UPDATE), you can use the following code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,when

df.withColumn('CGPA' , when((col('CGPA') > '5') | (col('CGPA') == '100'),(df.CGPA/25)).otherwise(df['CGPA'])).show()

#df = df.withColumn('CGPA' , when((col('CGPA') > '5') | (col('CGPA') == '100'),(df.CGPA/25)).otherwise(df['CGPA']))
#df.show()
```

[image]

**If condition is AND, then use this code:**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,when

df = df.withColumn('CGPA' , when((col('CGPA') > '5') & (col('CGPA') == '100'),(df.CGPA/25)).otherwise(df['CGPA']))
df.show()
```

[image]

Comment: no, we have and operator not OR

Comment: So, both CGPA>5 and CGPA==100 should be satisfied? Indicating you only want to divide by 25 only when CGPA is equal to 100? Please correct me if I'm wrong. Updated the answer to include how to use and for the same case. Please check